# Flutter: Circle Avatar inside of Stream Builder has wrong proportion

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have my app set to display a user's profile image using a **circle avatar** once they sign in.  I'm using a **stream builder** to determine which image is picked out of multiple user documents in fire store (imgUrl) // firebase storage (actual image).  When I display the image on the app, it's zoomed in too far.  When I stretch the **width** of the web browser for a bigger window the picture continues to zoom in relative to the size of the window.  The image does not zoom in when stretching the window **horizontally**.

How do I set a fixed size for the **Circle Avatar** while inside a stream builder?  I have tried setting a fixed size for the body and column parents but I have been unsuccessful.  Thank you.

```
body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        // sized box used for temporary spacing
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
// ---------- Display users profile image ---------- //
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: collectionReference
                  .where("uid", isEqualTo: user.uid)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Text('Something went wrong.');
                }
                final data = snapshot.requireData;
                return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: data.size,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
// ---------- Circle Avatar ---------- //
                        return CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(data.docs[index]['profileImageUrl']),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

[image: Normal window]
[image: Wide window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image stretching with the Colmun here so probably wrapping `CircleAvatar` into `Fitted box` with `fit: BoxFit.contain` will solve your problem.